# Interrupting a long-lasting thread which embeds Python in the Windows C API

Tags: python, c++, windows, multithreading

I am trying to write a simple Windows API C++ code that allows arbitrary execution of Python code, but cuts off the execution if it lasts too long (say, five seconds). For simplicity, I currently pass a string containing the code to be executed into the function `PyRun_String()`.

This C++ is intended to be compiled into a .DLL, and my calling program that I am trying to extend does not have access to functions that would fork off a Python process or subprocess.

I have been told that `TerminateThread()` is an unsafe method of ending the thread because it can cause memory leaks and synchronization errors. How do I gracefully exit the function `PyRun_String()` in a thread?

My code is below:

```
#include "stdafx.h"

DWORD WINAPI pystr(__in LPVOID lpParameter)
{
    // Local Variables
    PyObject *pResult, *pDict, *pMod;
    char *str = (char*) lpParameter;

    // Initialize the Python Interpreter
    Py_Initialize();

    // Initialize the global and local space.
    pMod = PyImport_AddModule("__main__");
    pDict = PyModule_GetDict(pMod);

    // Run the Python String.
    pResult = PyRun_String(str, Py_file_input, pDict, pDict);

    // Exit
    Py_Finalize();
    return 0;
}

char* Run_PyString(char* str)
{
    // Local Variables
    HANDLE handle;
    DWORD  thread_id;

    // Create the Thread and wait for it to return
    handle = CreateThread(0, 0, pystr, (LPVOID) str, 0, &thread_id);
    WaitForSingleObject(handle, INFINITE);

    // Close the Thread Handle
    CloseHandle(handle);
    return "";
}
```

Comment: There is no way to gracefuly terminate the thread from outside without code inside the thread.

Comment: You get correct isolation and resource cleanup if you run the code in a separate process, which you can then terminate at will. Without that, you're out of luck. You can well leave the thread running in the background though, what's the problem with that?

Comment: Assuming you change the wait from `INFINITE` to 5 seconds, if the wait times out, you can start another thread that acquires the GIL via [`PyGILState_Ensure`](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/init.html#c.PyGILState_Ensure) and then calls `Py_Finalize`.